Why does my value not showing when I tried to console.log the value before actual updating?
I'm having a little bit of trouble why I can't console.log(value) in my system. What I'm trying to do is create an update function that will update the credentials, what I did is I fetch the data first using tanstack query. And then set the defaultValues by calling the fetch data.
I successfully fetch the data.
 const getUserCredentials = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['userCredentials', id],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/getUserCredentials/${id}`)
      if (!response.data) {
        throw new Error('No user credentials found')
      }
      return response.data
    }
  })

This is my credentialForm
  const credentialForm = useForm<CreateRoleAccountSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(CreateRoleAccountSchema)
  })


After that is I set the defaultValue of the forms.
<form onSubmit={credentialForm.handleSubmit(handleSubmitCredential)} className="space-y-8">
                  <div className='flex flex-col items-start justify-center gap-2'>
                    <p className='text-muted-foreground font-semibold pb-2'>Login Details</p>
                    <div className='w-full gap-4 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2'>
                      {/* Name(username), Email, Password, Role */}
                      <div className=''>
                        <FormField
                          control={credentialForm.control}
                          defaultValue={getUserCredentials.data?.name}
                          name="name"
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>Username*</FormLabel>
                              <FormControl>
                                <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" {...field} />
                              </FormControl>

                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />
                        <FormField
                          control={credentialForm.control}
                          name="password"
                          defaultValue={getUserCredentials.data?.password}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>Password*</FormLabel>
                              <FormControl>
                                <Input disabled={forcePassword} type='password' placeholder="password" {...field} />
                              </FormControl>
                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />

                        <div className="flex items-center pt-1 space-x-2">
                          <Switch id="force-change" onClick={(e) => setForcePassword((prev) => !prev)} />
                          <Label htmlFor="force-change">Force Change </Label>
                        </div>

                        <FormField
                          control={credentialForm.control}
                          name="email"
                          defaultValue={getUserCredentials.data?.email}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>Email*</FormLabel>
                              <FormControl>
                                <Input type='email' placeholder="Email" {...field} />
                              </FormControl>

                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div>
                        <FormField
                          control={credentialForm.control}
                          name="role"
                          defaultValue={getUserCredentials.data?.role}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>Role*</FormLabel>
                              <Select onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value}>
                                <FormControl>
                                  <SelectTrigger>
                                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a role" />
                                  </SelectTrigger>
                                </FormControl>
                                <SelectContent>
                                  {role === 'super_admin' && (
                                    <>
                                      <SelectItem value="division_office_admin">Division Office Admin</SelectItem>
                                      <SelectItem value="school_admin">School Admin</SelectItem>
                                    </>
                                  )}
                                  {role === 'division_office_admin' && (
                                    <>
                                      <SelectItem value="division_office">Division Office</SelectItem>
                                      <SelectItem value="teacher">Teacher</SelectItem>

                                    </>
                                  )}

                                  {/* {role === 'school_admin' && (

                                  )} */}


                                </SelectContent>
                              </Select>
                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />

                        <FormField
                          control={credentialForm.control}
                          name="affiliation"
                          defaultValue={getUserCredentials.data?.affiliation}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>Affiliation*</FormLabel>
                              <Select onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value}>
                                <FormControl>
                                  <SelectTrigger>
                                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a role" />
                                  </SelectTrigger>
                                </FormControl>
                                <SelectContent>
                                  {credentialForm.watch('role') === 'division_office_admin' && (
                                    <SelectItem value="division_office">Division Office Admin</SelectItem>
                                  )}
                                  {credentialForm.watch('role') === 'school_admin' && (
                                    <SelectItem value="school">School</SelectItem>
                                  )}

                                  {role === 'division_office_admin' && (
                                    <>
                                      <SelectItem value="division_office">Divison Office</SelectItem>
                                      <SelectItem value="school">School</SelectItem>
                                    </>
                                  )}
                                  {role === 'school_admin' && (
                                    <SelectItem value="school">School</SelectItem>
                                  )}


                                </SelectContent>
                              </Select>
                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <Button type='submit'>
                    {updateCredential.isPending ? 'Pending...' : 'Update'}
                  </Button>
                </form>

Now, the problem happens when I tried to submit the data and console.log the values.

  const handleSubmitCredential = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
  }


This is my zod credentials. Does it affect the submit function even though there is already a data to it?

export const CreateRoleAccountSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(6, { message: "Username must be at least 6 letters" }), // Fixed typo and increased min length
    password: z.string().min(2, {
        message: " Password must be at least 2 characters"
    }),
    email: z.string().email({ message: "Invalid email format" }),
    role: z.enum([
        "super_admin",
        "division_office_admin",
        "division_office",
        "school_admin",
        "teacher",
      ]),
    affiliation: z.enum(['division_office', 'school'], {
        errorMap: () => ({ message: "Select a valid Affiliation" })
    }),})

export type CreateRoleAccountSchemaType = z.infer<typeof CreateRoleAccountSchema>



